# Android NDK error: cannot find the required library and undefined reference error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to generate .so files from native C++ code.This is my Android.mk file:

```
#this directory variable declaration
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

FFMPEG_PREBUILT_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/armeabi/

#mconfnativeshowvideo module START
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := mconfnativeshowvideo

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
                   mconfnative/DrawerManager.cpp \
                   mconfnative/VideoDrawer.cpp

LOCAL_CXXFLAGS := -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/common \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/queue \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/thread \
                                $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := queue thread common decode
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -L$(FFMPEG_PREBUILT_PATH) -lavcodec

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#mconfnativeshowvideo module END

#mconfnativeencodevideo module START
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := mconfnativeencodevideo

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
                   mconfnative/EncoderManager.cpp \
                   mconfnative/VideoEncoder.cpp \
                                   mconfnative/ImageRotator.cpp

LOCAL_CXXFLAGS := -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/common \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/queue \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/thread \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := queue thread common encode

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#mconfnativeencodevideo module END


#thread module
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := thread

LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -std=gnu++0x

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/common

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  \
                    iva/thread/ConditionVariable.cpp \
                    iva/thread/Interval.cpp \
                    iva/thread/Interval_linux.cpp \
                    iva/thread/Microseconds.cpp \
                    iva/thread/Milliseconds.cpp \
                    iva/thread/Mutex.cpp \
                    iva/thread/Seconds.cpp \
                    iva/thread/Thread.cpp \
                    iva/thread/Timer.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#end of thread module

#common module
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := common

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := thread

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/thread \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/common \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -L$(FFMPEG_PREBUILT_PATH) -lavcodec -lavutil

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  \
                    iva/common/AVConfigs.cpp \
                    iva/common/CommonColor.cpp \
                    iva/common/CommonRect.cpp \
                    iva/common/Directory.cpp \
                    iva/common/Directory_linux.cpp \
                    iva/common/ErrorController.cpp \
                    iva/common/ErrorData.cpp \
                    iva/common/ErrorStack.cpp \
                    iva/common/ErrorVector.cpp \
                    iva/common/Folders.cpp \
                    iva/common/IPV4.cpp \
                    iva/common/IvaOutBuffer.cpp \
                    iva/common/IvaOutController.cpp \
                    iva/common/IvaOutLogFile.cpp \
                    iva/common/IvaOutStream.cpp \
                    iva/common/IvaPixFmt.cpp \
                    iva/common/IvaPixFmt_linux.cpp \
                    iva/common/IvaString.cpp \
                    iva/common/IvaTime.cpp \
                    iva/common/IvaVideoFrame.cpp \
                    iva/common/Location.cpp \
                    iva/common/LogData.cpp \
                    iva/common/SysInfo_linux.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#end of common module

#queue module
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := queue

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := thread common

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/thread \
            $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/common \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  iva/queue/queue.cpp \
                    iva/queue/QueueBuffer.cpp \
                    iva/queue/QueueDiscard.cpp \
                    iva/queue/QueueDiscardPolicy.cpp \
                    iva/queue/QueueExtraData.cpp \
                    iva/queue/QueueExtraDataAudio.cpp \
                    iva/queue/QueueExtraDataVideo.cpp  

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#end of queue module

#decode module
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := decode

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := thread common queue

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/thread \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/common \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/queue \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/decode \
                                $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(FFMPEG_PREBUILT_PATH) -lavcodec -lavutil -lswscale

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  iva/decode/Decode.cpp \
            iva/decode/DecodeAudio.cpp \
            iva/decode/DecodeVideo.cpp  

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#end of decode module

#encode module
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := encode

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := thread common queue

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(FFMPEG_PREBUILT_PATH) -lavcodec -lavutil -lswscale -lavformat

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/thread \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/common \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/queue \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/iva/encode \
                                $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=          iva/encode/Encode.cpp \
                    iva/encode/EncodeAudio.cpp \
                    iva/encode/EncodeAudioParams.cpp \
                    iva/encode/EncodeVideo.cpp \
                    iva/encode/EncodeVideoParams.cpp \
                    iva/encode/VideoLoader.cpp  

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#end of encode module
```

When I am trying to build my project using Android NDK it gives the following error

```
/home/iamharsh/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130717/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lavcodec
/home/iamharsh/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130717/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lavutil
/home/iamharsh/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130717/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/common/iva/common/IvaVideoFrame.o: in function IvaVideoFrame::freeInternalData():jni/iva/common/IvaVideoFrame.cpp:19: error: undefined reference to 'avpicture_free'
/home/iamharsh/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130717/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/common/iva/common/IvaVideoFrame.o: in function IvaVideoFrame::freeInternalData():jni/iva/common/IvaVideoFrame.cpp:20: error: undefined reference to 'av_free'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libcommon.so] Error 1
```

The functions av_free and avpicture_free are present in different header files in a different directory. Thus I tried importing them by using the relative path but still no good. Any help or advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is FFMPEG_PREBUILT_PATH the correct location for libavcodec and libavutil? The functions the linker is looking for should be in those libraries, so I think it's the fact that they can't be found that's causing the problem.

Comment: Did you actually build  avcodec and avutil for android?  Have you build them as static or as dynamic libraries?

Comment: Yes I have built them and have used them as static libraries